# JNDI lookup of EJB with new InitialContext each time?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jndi, ejb-3.0

We use `EJB3` and `JBOSS` application Server in our Application. I have a Bean lookup utility method where its a generic method written to lookup stateless EJB Beans by JNDI name:

```
public class BeanFactory {

    static  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BeanFactory.class.getName());
    /**
     * 
     * @param jndiName
     * @return
     */
    public static <T> T lookup(String jndiName){

        logger.info("Inside bean BeanFactory lookup: " + jndiName);
        
        T handle = null;

        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            handle = (T) ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
        return handle;
    }
```

So there are classes which have dependencies on Beans and they use lookup method to invoke the methods of the Bean. For Example

```
 private AuthenticationProfileDTO getAuthenticationProfile(String credId) throws OneM2MException {
            
            ResourceProceduresDao dao = BeanFactory.lookup(ResourceProceduresDao.JNDI_NAME);
            
            AuthenticationProfileRemote apRemote = BeanFactory.lookup(AuthenticationProfileRemote.JNDI_NAME);
            
            AuthenticationProfileDTO authenticationProfileDTO;
    
            if (isKpsaId(credId))
                authenticationProfileDTO = apRemote.getAuthenticationProfileDTOForSymmKeyID(credId);
            else
                authenticationProfileDTO = apRemote.getAuthenticationProfileDTOForCredentialID(credId);
            return authenticationProfileDTO;
        }
```

So now when we ran **JProfiler** on the code the `lookup` method is coming to be time consuming because every time `lookup` is called a new `InitialContext` is instantiated.

I was thinking of making the InitialContext static so that only once it's initialized in a static block, but I don't know what implications will it have in terms of getting Bean instances. Since this piece of code is managed by EJB Container, the run time impacts are unknown. After looking up some articles online not much clarity was there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason not to inject it directly with `@Inject` or `@EJB`? As for the static `InitialContext`, that may not work as it needs different contexts per component dependency on the deployment.

Comment: Besides the main point, but you can save 1 line of code and a cast by using `javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup(String)`

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The class where I am calling the lookup method is a normal Java class and not an EJB. As per my knowledge, Injection annotation EJB works only in EJB beans

Comment: So why is it necessary to access EJBs of any kind from a non-EJB-context (normal Java class)? If there isn't a request based context, e.g. driven by user interaction I'd always use @Scheduled-annotation or any similar EJB-way of invoking things. From my point of view this is the only way to stay on the safe side and avoid any leakage. (You cannot simply replicate state changes from non-EJB parts through application server magic into multi instance setups.)

Comment: Aside from that I urge you to improve your interface. Upon any Exception that method returns `null` with only a log message. The caller does not receive any useful information if this is a recoverable or finalizing error. What if a set of JNDI names must be orchestrated with some missing completely, one failing because of an IOException/ network error and two others successfully returned? You approach is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that javadoc for `InitialContext` warns that:

```
An InitialContext instance is not synchronized against concurrent
access by multiple threads. Multiple threads each manipulating a
different InitialContext instance need not synchronize.
Threads that need to access a single InitialContext instance
concurrently should synchronize amongst themselves and provide the
necessary locking.
```

So, making the field static isn't necessarily a good idea as you'll need to synchronize each `lookup(jndiName)` call, and this may cause other issues as per comment by `James R. Perkins`.

However as you have shown that `getAuthenticationProfile(String credId)` calls `lookup` twice, there is no reason why you can't make a `BeanFactory` hold one `InitialContext` to reduce the number of instances by re-using `InitialContext` within same calling methods.

```
public class BeanFactory {

    private final InitialContext ctx;
    private BeanFactory(InitialContext initialContext) {
        this.ctx = initialContext;
    }
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BeanFactory.class.getName());
    /** JNDI lookup*/
    public <T> T lookup(String jndiName){
        // logger.info("Inside bean BeanFactory lookup: " + jndiName);
        try {
            return (T) ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException("Could not find jndi: "+jndiName, e);
            logger.error(re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
    /** Setup a new BeanFactory */
    public static BeanFactory create() {
       try {
            return new BeanFactory(new InitialContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create a new context", e);
            logger.error(re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

This allows `getAuthenticationProfile` to use a single `InitialContext` for 2 lookups:

```
BeanFactory ctx = BeanFactory.create();
ResourceProceduresDao            dao = ctx.lookup(ResourceProceduresDao.JNDI_NAME);
AuthenticationProfileRemote apRemote = ctx.lookup(AuthenticationProfileRemote.JNDI_NAME);
```

You might also consider whether saving `BeanFactory` as a thread local would help though I would be **very** concerned about doing this an application server because you may have little control over which and how many threads instantiate `InitialContext` and what from what context they run.  However it might be suitable within a standalone client program accessing your EJB server logic:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<BeanFactory> BEANS = ThreadLocal.withInitial(BeanFactory::create);
private static BeanFactory local() {
    return BEANS.get();
}
// Example lookups:
ResourceProceduresDao            dao = BeanFactory.local().lookup(ResourceProceduresDao.JNDI_NAME);
AuthenticationProfileRemote apRemote = BeanFactory.local().lookup(AuthenticationProfileRemote.JNDI_NAME);
```

Comment: How does this synchronize in any way? Your solution does not outline what similarity or equality means. A ThreadLocal bound to different threads caused by the same user session still don't synchronize in any way nor replicate state changes. It also does not take a shared thread pool into consideration where different (user) sessions might see residue in the ThreadLocal of previous thread activity.

Comment: @motzmann A thread local variable means that `BEANS.get()` call returns a dedicated per-thread instance => no need to synchronize as multiple threads never share `InitialContext` instances. ThreadLocal approach has higher risk / limited use and only suitable in appropriate circumstances (hence my reservations in "consider whether ... very concerned" section) especially if an application server is controlling the thread creation / tasks / sessions, but may be worth considering for tasks launched by an applications own threads / executor queues.

Comment: I am aware of the inner workings but it is not clear how threads are related to the call stack involved. Some dispatch thread could forward to different workers – must not share anything/ ThreadLocal ok. In contrast a main thread could split a complex processing task into threaded chunks – unsure about need for isolation/ ThreadLocal possibly not ok. (IniticalContext has various other methods that change state and a remote interface/ raw JNDI lookup suggests possible violation of scoping/ transaction control.)

Comment: @DuncG : You said "reduce the number of instances by re-using InitialContext within same calling methods" which is good. What if I extend this reuse per class ? I could keep one context per class and reuse for that class, same way you mentioned just within method. Should that be okay ??

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha It depends on use. One per class means you may be back with the problem that synchronize access is required.

Comment: @DuncG : I have couple of doubts : 1. So my class has many methods and each wants to use Dao Bean. So this means I would need separate lookup per method to avoid synchronization issue ? 2. Now, in EJB beans, I use EJB injection (via annotation) instead of lookup myself. So there I can use injected bean as class member variable without synchronization worries ?